# How do I make execution stop on promise rejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to benefit from promises instead of all these nested functions. The code below works (in a way lol). The problem is when it detects that a username or email exists, it returns `"Email is already in use."` or `"Username is already in use."` and then still executes the last promise `p3` which adds the user to the database (which it shouldn't). Maybe I'm misconceiving the concept. What is the right way to do this?

```
var p1 = new Promise(
    (res, rej) => {

        Database.doesEmailExist(userObj.email,

            (err, exists) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                if(exists) return rej("Email is already in use.");
                return res();
            }

        );


    }
);

var p2 = new Promise(
    (res, rej) => {

        Database.doesUsernameExist(userObj.username,

            (err, exists) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                if(exists) return rej("Username is already in use.");
                return res();

            }

        )
    }
);

var p3 = new Promise(
    (res, rej) => {

        Database.addUserToDB(userObj.username, userObj.email, bcrypt.hashSync(userObj.password),

            (err) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                return res();

            }

        )

    }
);

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(success => {

    return callback("true", "You have successfully registered.");

}).catch(reason => {

    return callback("false", reason);

});
```

Comment: Still executes what other statements?  `Promise.all()` runs all operations in parallel.  If you want them to run in sequence, you need a different scheme.  As always, we can help you better if you describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: sorry, i explained that poorly. Will edit. So say a username exists in the database. It will run the `rej()` and return to the user "Username is already in use" but then it doesn't stop the execution of the next Promise `p3`. It will add the user to the DB even though the previous promise rejected.

Comment: Because you've already started all three async operations.  `Promise.all()` just monitors all three and tells you when they have all finished or any one of them rejected.  If you want to sequence your operations and only execute the next step when the previous step finished successfully, then please describe what you want in your question.

Comment: Like jfriend00 is saying, for this solution you should run `Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(...` and inside that `then` statement, return p3

Comment: OMG! I am an idiot. The `then` couldn't be any clearer in syntax and I somehow figured out a way to botch it. I am embarrassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running p1, p2 and p3 at the same time: the promises are run, and than Promise.all waits untill all of them are finished.

You should first check if the username and the email are valid, *then* save the new user.

```
var checkEmail = () => new Promise(
    (res, rej) => {
        Database.doesEmailExist(userObj.email,

            (err, exists) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                if(exists) return rej("Email is already in use.");
                return res();
            }

        );


    }
);

var checkUsername = () => new Promise(
    (res, rej) => {

        Database.doesUsernameExist(userObj.username,

            (err, exists) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                if(exists) return rej("Username is already in use.");
                return res();

            }

        )
    }
);

var saveUser = () => new Promise(
    (res, rej) => {

        Database.addUserToDB(userObj.username, userObj.email, bcrypt.hashSync(userObj.password),

            (err) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                return res();

            }

        )

    }
);

Promise.all([ checkUsername(), checkEmail() ]).then(saveUser).then(() => {

    return callback("true", "You have successfully registered.");

}).catch(reason => {

    return callback("false", reason);

});
```

You code can be represented like this: (time is on the x axis)

```
p1          --------> .
p2          ---->     .
p3          ------>   .
____________________________________________
                      OK ? callback("true")
                      ERROR ? callback("false")
```

While mine is more like this:

```
checkEmail()    --------> .
checkUsername() ---->     .
saveUser()                . ---------------> .
________________________________________________
                          OK ? continue      OK ? callback("true")
                          ERROR ?            ERROR ? callback("false")
                                 \__________________/
```

Comment: I answered too late, it looks like you already solved your problem 

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer. This cleared a lot up for me. Makes it super clean and neat too.